# How to check if certain digits exist in a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if the three digits 1,3,5 exists in a string ... or 2,7,9

for example: 
string 18637775 is accepted
string 25553373349 is accepted
string 123 is rejected
string 5631 is accepted

so how can i write this in regex form!

```
I got this: \\d*1+\\d*3+\\d*5+\\d*
```

... but doesn't this mean that string 5631 wouldn't be accepted .. how to make 1,3,5 be accepted for their presence and not the order they appear in.

Comment: Do you want to use regex strictly? Don't want other methods like substring check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing answer in addition to a comment just to clearly show the code.

When you run the below Perl script you would get "123 does not match" as the output.

```
my $a = "123";
if($a =~ /(?=.*5.*)(?=.*3.*)(?=.*1.*)|(?=.*2.*)(?=.*7.*)(?=.*9.*)/)
{
        print "$a matches";
}
else
{
        print "$a does not match";
}
```

Comment: Yep :), will do that from next time onwards. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mohamed for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lookahead here like this:

```
^((?=[^1]*1)(?=[^3]*3)(?=[^5]*5)|(?=[^2]*2)(?=[^7]*7)(?=[^9]*9))\\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written and tried the below regex in Perl and it passes all the test cases you specified. Hope, the same would work in Java also.

```
(?=.*5.*)(?=.*3.*)(?=.*1.*)|(?=.*2.*)(?=.*7.*)(?=.*9.*)
```

Comment: This checks one set OR the other, where the request is one set AND NOT the other. It accepts the OP's "123", for example.

Comment: When you run the below Perl script you would get "123 does not match" as the output. 

my $a = "123";
if($a =~ /(?=.*5.*)(?=.*3.*)(?=.*1.*)|(?=.*2.*)(?=.*7.*)(?=.*9.*)/)
{
 print "$a matches";
}
else
{
 print "$a does not match";
}

Comment: Apologies -- the question was unclear and so I assumed one must also check for the NOT cases (i.e., `if(135 && !279)`, and the reverse).

Comment: Even now you have not clearly mentioned :) . Do you mean 25553373349  should be rejected as it contains 2,7 and 9?

Comment: There no needs of the second `.*` in each lookahead, `(?=.*5)` would suffice.